# Unity Texture2DArray is too noisy

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, textures

I've generated a `Texture2DArray` from array of Texture2Ds and for some reason, when my shader is using `Texture Array` the output colors are noisy, almost as if noise filter was applied on them. Compare,

Just `Texture2D`:
[image]

And when using `Texture2DArray`:
[image]

I generate array using this code:

```
        Texture2D sample = materials[0].albedo;
        materialArray = new Texture2DArray(sample.width, sample.height, 
        materials.Count * 4, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Count; i += 4)
        {
            T_Material material = materials[i];

            materialArray.SetPixels(material.albedo.GetPixels(), i);
            materialArray.SetPixels(material.normal.GetPixels(), i + 1);
            materialArray.SetPixels(material.occulusion.GetPixels(), i + 2);
            materialArray.SetPixels(material.rougness.GetPixels(), i + 3);

        }
        materialArray.Apply(true);
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(materialArray, "Assets/_Generated/" + "terrainTextures.asset");
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
```

Initial Texture2Ds are in `RGBA 32bit` format:

[image]

Generated `Texture2DArray` (4 Textures, `albedo`, `normal`, `AO`, `roughness`, But I am only using albedo in shader for now):

[image]

My shader is simple, it extracts color data from `Texture2DArray` using index and applies it to PBR's albedo input.

[image]

And yes, I tried without my special blending effects, just inserting `RGBA4` output to Albedo input of PBR both from `Texture2DArray` sampler and directly from `Texture2D` sampler.

Results were the same, `Texture2DArray` is noisy!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
materialArray = new Texture2DArray(sample.width, sample.height, 
    materials.Count * 4, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
```

That `false` says "Do not generate mipmaps for this texture array".

Without [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), you get spatial aliasing - the noise you're observing.

Pass `true` to generate mipmaps. Then when sampling that texture for a distant surface, the GPU will automatically select a smaller mipmap, which is pre-filtered to smooth out that noise.

Comment: Aghh! When I mouseovered this parameter, it was called "mipchain", I got confused and thought better not touch it. Thank you so much! That solved the problem. BTW, if I set textures to be 4k, are they all loaded into GPU VRAM directly?

Comment: A "mip chain" means a chain of mipmaps. One half the size, the next a quarter, then an eighth, etc. When in doubt, it helps to check the docs/look up the term or ask a question here to clarify the term. 